# Aren't the words ostream and istream switched in the text below?

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream, istream

I'm trying to understand I/O Streams in more detail, and for this, I'm reading the "The C++ Programming Language" by Stroustrup, 4th edition. Right at the beginning of Chapter 38, page 1073, one finds the following two statements:

An **ostream** converts typed objects to a stream of characters (bytes).

[image]

An **istream** converts a stream of characters (bytes) to typed objects.

[image]

Aren't the words **ostream** and **istream** switched in the explanation given above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `ostream` "outputs" from arbitrary types to character sequences, and `istream` "inputs" to arbitrary types from character sequences, just as described.

Comment: What does the author mean by "typed object"?

Comment: @Ayrosa: An object with a type, like `int` or `double` or a user-defined class type. The book should cover the type system in detail.

Comment: Pretty clear now. My problem was not the concept, but the English language. Somehow I was reading "type" as from the verb "to type" and this confused me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Outputting is receiving some typed objects from the program (a `char` 'c', an `int` 123, a `float` 123.45) and encoding them into a sequence of bytes, sent somewhere (to a printer, to a file, to the console...).

Inputting is receiving a stream of bytes from somewhere ant extracting some typed data from it.

The images are correct.